# st_union for XYZ polygon from R's sf package

Tags: r

I have to perform union of polygons with a third dimension (XYZ or XYM).
When using st_union, the value of Z (or M) for the new points at intersection of two polygons receive a value corresponding to the mean of of the value at the edges of the crossing segments (see example beloaw).
Is there a solution to define the function that calculate the new Z (or  M) values ?
Or at least that the new points received a NA value ?
Thank you for your help.

```
m = as.matrix(data.frame(X=c(0,1,1,0,0), Y=c(0,0,1,1,0), Z=c(1,1,1,1,1)))
p = st_polygon(x=list(m), dim="XYZ")
n = 3
l = vector("list", n)
for (i in 1:n)
  l[[i]] = p + 1 * c(runif(2), i)
s = st_sfc(l)
plot(s, col = sf.colors(categorical = TRUE, alpha = .5))
title("overlapping squares")

(aa = as.data.frame(st_coordinates(s)))
text(aa$X, aa$Y, aa$Z)

i = st_union(s) # st_union
windows()
plot(i, col = sf.colors(categorical = TRUE, alpha = .5))
title("st_union")

(aa = as.data.frame(st_coordinates(i)))
text(aa$X, aa$Y, aa$Z)
```

Comment: You're `union`ing three parallel polygons, so there's no steric intersection, only overlaps of their vertical shadows on the XY-plane. Any "crossing point" of, say, planes A and B represents thus one point on plane A with z-value z_a and one on plane B with z-value z_b. Which other value (than the mean of z_a and z_b) should be assigned?

Comment: For my project, I need to define the value by myself. I don'y want it to be the mean. At least, it would be ok if it was possible that the  M (or Z) value was NA or 0 for the "crossing points". Library clipper2 in cpp allows that.